# duplicate print problam in eclipse java

Tags: java, eclipse, duplicates

My question is about duplicate print, received from the code below

```
 package Project_Package;

 import java.io.*;
 import java.net.*;
 import java.util.Scanner;

class TCPClient_with_serialized {

public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {

    String Result = null;
    Object s = null;
    Object l = null;
    Info Detail = null;
    int Sign=0;
    String Type, username, password;

    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 10000);
    Scanner inFromUser = new Scanner(System.in);
    ObjectOutputStream outToServer = new 
ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("----Choose user interface:----");
        System.out.println("#1 House Committee");
        System.out.println("#2 Tenant");
        Type = inFromUser.nextLine();
        switch (Type) {
        case "1":

            break;

        case "2":

    System.out.println("----Dear Tenant:----");
            System.out.println("#1 Login With your Username and Password");
            System.out.println("#2 Change your password");

            String Choise = inFromUser.next();
            if (Choise.matches("1")) {
                System.out.println("enter Username");
                username = inFromUser.next();
                System.out.println("enter Password");
                password = inFromUser.next();
                Detail = new Info(username, password, Type, Choise);
                outToServer.writeObject(Detail);
                String modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
                System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);
                if (modifiedSentence.matches("Ok")) {
                    System.out.println("----Dear Tenant:----");
                    System.out.println("#1 Would you like to see your payments");
                    System.out.println("#2 Would you like to complain about a flaw");
                    Sign = inFromUser.nextInt();
                    outToServer.writeInt(Sign);
                    if (Sign==1) {
                        modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
                        System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);

                    }

                }

            }
            if (Choise.matches("2")) {
                System.out.println("enter Username");
                username = inFromUser.next();
                System.out.println("enter your New Password");
                password = inFromUser.next();
                Detail = new Info(username, password, Type, Choise);
                outToServer.writeObject(Detail);
                String modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
                System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);
                break;
            }

            default:
                break;
        }

    }
}

}
```

So the problem appears in the next part below that part of code been printed twice in scenario that the user/client clicked 2 and then 3, instead of once.
I think that the problem is in the `break` statement inside the `loops` but I am not sure of that.

```
("----Choose user interface:----");
("#1 House Committee");
("#2 Tenant");
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo

Comment: Thx you very much work fine now